# Haml link not rendering as a link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am trying to create a simple link in HAML like this:

```
link_to "Create Profile", home
```

But for some reason it is rendering it all as plain text.

Any idea why that might happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to put equal sign `=`?

```
= link_to "Create Profile", home
```

Comment: yes that was the case...newbie mistake.. But now I got this problem: undefined local variable or method `home' for #<#<Class:0x129977640>:0x129967e20> and the home is a defined path...any idea why the error happens?

Comment: Maybe `home_path` is what you need?

Comment: I have no superpower to discover what methods/variables are defined in your program. Please, run the `rake routes` command from ther root of your application and show me the output. This way I'll be able to tell what paths are defined in your program.

Answer (score 0):

At first run

```
rake routes
```

in your terminal to check for all routes. Than pick up the right one, for example root_path so the link_to helper call will look like:

```
= link_to 'Create Profile', home_path
```

Also you can practice link_to method in rails console like this:

```
1.9.3-head :030 >   include ActionView::Helpers::UrlHelper
 => Object 
1.9.3-head :031 > link_to 'Home', '/home'
 => "<a href=\"/home\">Home</a>"
```

And my last advice - "Don't be afraid of reading the source", here is the source of link_to method and others in Rails:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/url_helper.rb#L236